# fork() is very slow

Tags: ubuntu, performance, fork, clone

I have a Linux server running Ubuntu 18.04 on a VM. Executing any task like `ls -l` or `w` frequently takes several seconds to finish. `strace -c ls -l` says `ls` only takes a few milliseconds, but running `strace -c strace -c ls -l` a bunch of times until the problem occurred told me that the clone() syscall is causing the problem:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.33    1.374858      687429         2           clone
  0.31    0.004273           8       548         1 wait4
  0.20    0.002701           2      1088           ptrace
  0.10    0.001416           1      1096           rt_sigprocmask
  0.01    0.000130           6        22           mmap
...
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    1.384096                  2893        15 total
```

Every diagnostic I've run seemed OK: RAM/CPU usage, process/thread count, IO performance, etc. Everything is up to date. The problem randomly started occurring a few weeks ago and persisted after rebooting. Does anybody know of anything that could be causing this issue? The server is pretty much useless in this current state.

Comment: You say this is running in a VM, how is the health of the host it is running on when you see the problems?  Check the host for CPU and RAM usage.

Comment: Any security or auditing mechanism in place such as apparmor, auditd, an antivirus? If yes, does disabling it make a difference?

Comment: The technical support deemed the performance of the server to be within the norm, so I'm switching to a KVM-based server that's supposed to be faster. Thank you anyway